# Usage of *was going to do*

Tags: meaning, tenses

The following is 
[an article by Patrick Wintour in The Guardian website](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/2015/jun/03/undoing-of-ed-miliband-and-how-labour-lost-election).

> Miliband’s team admitted that they were slow to realise the danger. One close adviser admitted that he was initially perplexed as to why posters were appearing all over English towns that depicted Miliband in the pocket of Alex Salmond. “They stumbled on this SNP thing. We did not realise how much impact it would have, and perhaps they did not realise how much,” the close adviser said. “It **was going to persuade** 2.5% of the [electorate previously allied to Ukip] to go back into the Tory fold. It made us the risk.”

I learned that we can use *was/were going to* for a past intention or arrangement.
It seems that the usage of **was going to persuade**  in the above article doesn't match neither of the two descriptions. What is the meaning of this phrase and why is that?

NOTE: *It* (the subject of **was going to persuade**) = this SNP thing = the threat of SNP = the risks of a minority Labour government.

Comment: The close advisor was speaking in hindsight. The SNP strategy **did** persuade 2.5% of the electorate to vote strategically to make sure Labour didn't get to form a coalition government with the nationalist SNP. He is saying that although the Tories knew they had hit upon an effective strategy, they themselves didn't realise just **how** effective it would actually turn out to be!

Comment: @JulieCarter , then he talked  after the election about the result of the election  (2.5% of UKIP supporters voted for the Tories)  from the view point of the time prior to the election when nobody knew how much effect it would achieve.  It is not "intention in the past" nor "arrangement in the past". What is it? What is the difference from "it persuaded 2.5%" or "it had persuaded 2.5%"?

Comment: I have posted an answer, which I hope is useful for you. If you want to know more about the grammar theory you might like to edit this question or post another. Best wishes

Comment: You're very welcome @Aki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close adviser to the Labour Party is speaking after the election results have come through and says:

> 'They [*the Tories*] stumbled on this SNP thing. We [*Labour*] did not realise how much impact it would have, and perhaps they [*the Tories*] did not realise how much.'

He then says:

> 'It **was going** to persuade 2.5% of the [electorate previously allied to UKIP] to go back into the Tory fold. It **made** us [*Labour*] the risk.'

The adviser can only say 2.5% of the electorate were to be persuaded to vote Tory, (instead of their preferred UKIP), from a position of hindsight, that is, from knowing that this is actually what happened.

The Tories could have predicted or estimated or hoped! that approximately 2.5% of the electorate would change their vote as a result of their anti-Labour/SNP coalition campaign, but they would never have known for sure...until after the election.

If you say something **is** or **was** going to happen, it means that the plan or arrangement is a definite one. It **will** or **did** happen.

It is acceptable, as above, to use '**was going to**' when you are speaking about something you know **has** happened as a result of another prior action or event. From the future (after the election and when they've analysed the results), the adviser can look back and say that launching  the anti-SNP campaign was going to persuade people to change their vote, because he knows that it did.

Answer (score 1):

At time A in the past,the Tories recognized that it would be a winning political strategy to tie Miliband (the leader of the Labor Party) to the Scottish National Party (SNP).  At time B, an election was held in which a crucial 2.5% of voters who might have voted for the Independence Party (UKIP) instead voted for the Tory Party, which meant a loss for Labor.

Between A and B (both times in the past) The abovementioned strategy "was going to persuade [that] 2.5%" to switch to the Tories.  Sounds like an ongoing past arrangement to me.

Comment: The term "arrangement" suggests 
that the Tory estimated that the effect would be 2.5%,
which I think contradicts the statement immediately before the phrase we are concerned
"perhaps they (Tory) did not realise how much(impact it would have)".

Comment: "Arrangement" doesn't appear in the paragraph but in the description of the verb tense.  It might as well have been "situation."  Isn't the close advisor someone advising Labor?  I don't think UKIP turned out to be the problem; I think it was the losses of the Liberal Democratic Party, but that's really beyond the scope of ELU.  Does the verb tense make sense to you?

Comment: I meant that if we interpret the past tense use of "be going to" as "arrangement in the past" sense then it doesn't fit in the context.If the adviser meant that the Tories had expected before the election 
5% of the electorate to switch to the Tories, then he didn't say that "they did not realize how much".